# DRF test Swagger Fake View in get_queryset

Tags: django, testing, django-rest-framework, pytest, drf-yasg

I am able to test `get_queryset()` in `ReadOnlyModelViewSet` like this:

```py
class CatalogViewTests(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.cur_user = UserFactory()
        self.cur_dataset = DataSetFactory(created_by=self.cur_user)

    @patch.object(CatalogView, "permission_classes", [])
    def test_get_queryset(self):
        url = reverse('data_tab:catalog-list')
        response = self.client.get(url, format='json', **{DATASET_ID: self.cur_dataset.id})
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**views.py**

```py
class CatalogView(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    Returns the Data tab catalog page with pagination
    """

    serializer_class = CatalogSerializer
    permission_classes = [UserHasDatasetChangeAccess]
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    queryset = TableMeta.objects.all()
    renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer]
    ordering_fields = ["created_on", "modified_on"]
    ordering = ["-modified_on"]

    def get_queryset(self):
        if getattr(self, "swagger_fake_view", False):
            # queryset just for schema generation metadata
            return TableMeta.objects.none()
        return TableMeta.objects.filter(
            dataset=get_object_or_404(DataSet, id=self.request.META.get(DATASET_ID, ""))
        ).prefetch_related(
            "table_columns", "table_metrics", "table_relationship_source"
        )
```

The *TestCase* is running correctly and I am getting the output as expected.
But in test_report this line is not tested.

[image]

As we can see the red line is still showing untested because it is expecting the `swagger_faker_view` variable to be **True**.

Does anyone know how to write a test case for this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another decorator to your test to apply this like so:

```py
@patch.object(CatalogView, "swagger_fake_view", True, create=True)
```

Comment: Error is coming <class 'fin_reporting.data_tab.views.CatalogView'> does not have the attribute 'swagger_fake_view'

Comment: Ah yes please add `create=True`. I edited the answer

Comment: Thankyou very much this works .